# MonoDroid onClick From XML No Such Method Error

Tags: android, xamarin.android

LiftInspection.axml

```
<Button
      android:id="@+id/expandCollapse1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/expand_arrow"
      android:text="Function/Controls"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:background="@drawable/expandCollapseButton"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:onClick="button_Click"/>
```

LiftInspection.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LiftInspection);
    }

public void button_Click(View view)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Testing", ToastLength.Long).Show();           
    }
```

As soon as I click the button, the app crashes and forces close.  In the Android Log, I find  "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method button_Click(View) in the activity class cpecfieldapp.LiftInspection for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id'expandCollapse1'"

Everything I've found on setting up a click event from xml only shows what I'm doing.  Putting it in android:onClick from XML and having a public void where the only parameter is a View in the activity implementing that layout. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not something that's supported in the current version of Mono for Android. You can refer to [this bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=382) for more details about it.

Comment: The forthcoming 4.1.0 alpha release will support this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this to work by adding the `[Export]` attribute to your `button_Click` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible. You need to do three things:

1. Reference `Mono.Android.Export`
2. `using Java.Interop`
3. Annotate your event method like this:

```cs
[Export ("button_Click")]  
public void button_Click(View view)  
    {  
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Testing", ToastLength.Long).Show();             
    }
```